# Google maps Places returns zero result. Why?

Tags: google-maps

This URL returns zero results.
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=48.015745,37.80285&radius=10000&types=restaurants&name=harbour&sensor=false&key=PUT_YOUR_KEY

It is Donetsk city in Ukraine. Does it mean that in Donetsk we don't have any places?

Comment: Are you changing PUT_YOUR_KEY to your actual developer key from the [Google APIs Developer Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/)? Don't post it here, because then others could use your developer key.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for suggestion, but this keys will work only on my domain, and access for this domain is only for me :)

Comment: Server side keys aren't restricted to domains but to IP addresses. What I was suggesting, however, was that in the URL you have key=PUT_YOUR_KEY. Do you replace that in the actual request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're asking for restaurants in a 10000 radius of Donetsk in Ukraine.

The query returns

```
{
    "html_attributions": [ ],
    "results": [ ],
    "status": "ZERO_RESULTS"
}
```

It doesn't mean there are no restaurants in Donetsk, but simply that Google Places has no records of such places. I think I saw an hotel on the map, but no restaurants on Maps, no.

Comment: So to define restaurants, I can't use google places? Why this displays a lot of restaurants? http://maps.google.com.ua/maps?q=Restaurants&hl=ru&sll=48.003821,37.800694&sspn=0.047378,0.111494&vpsrc=0&hq=Restaurants&t=m&z=14

Comment: It seems like right now you can't, but maybe if some get added to their index in the future, you will be able to. In your link, it is just that in this particular town, Google has indexed more places than in your other town.