# Adding you own place using Google places API in android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api-java-client, google-places-api

i want to add my own place using Google places API in android I am using the following code snippet, however it give me this exception:

com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: 400 Bad Request

My code snippet is:

```
private static final String PLACE_ADD_URL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/add/json?"; 
public PlacesList addPlace() throws Exception {

try {
        Log.v(LOG_KEY, "Adding Place...");
        GenericUrl reqUrl = new GenericUrl(PLACE_ADD_URL);
        reqUrl.put("key", API_KEY);
        reqUrl.put("sensor", "false");
        Log.v(LOG_KEY, "Adding Place...");
        //reqUrl.put("Host:", "maps.googleapis.com");
        reqUrl.put("Host: maps.googleapis.com","{\"location\":{\"lat\":-33.8733721,\"lng\":151.2012871},\"accuracy\":50.0,\"name\":\"harbour\",\"types\":[\"food\"],\"language\":\"en\"}");
        Log.v(LOG_KEY, "Requested URL= " + reqUrl);

        HttpRequestFactory httpRequestFactory = createRequestFactory(transport);
        HttpRequest request = httpRequestFactory.buildGetRequest(reqUrl);


        Log.v(LOG_KEY, request.execute().parseAsString());  
        PlacesList place = request.execute().parseAs(PlacesList.class);

        Log.v(LOG_KEY, "STATUS = " + place.status); 
        Log.v(LOG_KEY, "Place Added is = " + place);    

            return place;

    } catch (HttpResponseException e) {
        Log.v(LOG_KEY, e.getResponse().parseAsString());
        throw e;
    }

    catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Now i played a lot with this exception but cant solved, how i should pass this request URL? is my approach is correct or wrong??

Comment: Try this url it might work for you String url ="http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr="+YOUR.LATITUDE+","+YOUR_LONGITUDE+"&daddr="+latitude+","+longitude;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was return Key as null. Now i passes correct key and It works fine

Comment: hehe, what do you mean my ID @NaeemShah? email? just post on stack overflow. The only problem I have I cannot see added places on search, and url is not in details response. See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8444880/google-maps-places-returns-zero-result-why/9705117#9705117

Comment: hi i am using same code and get same problem ,please provide another way.

Comment: when you perform a search, can you filter and get only your own places?